# Windows 10 IoT Core Needs Explaining

Tags: windows-iot

First I am going to start with that I have a Raspberry Pi 2 B+ and a SanDisk 32GB class 10 micro SD card. My question is where is some good solid documentation, or at least a good explanation on what Windows 10 IoT Core does, what it looks like, and how to install it? I have looked for documentation or at least a YouTube video but to no avail. I think that I am starting to figure out how to do it but some guidance on the above questions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They way I view Windows IoT currently is that it allows you to make your Raspberry Pi serve as an output device for your C# binaries created in Visual Studio.

There's no desktop environment, only a command shell. The only way to install any program is to write an App for it (or use an App which was written by someone else).

The official instruction is this:

https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/SetupRPI.htm

I found the following video pretty instructional as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oo_gNL-zkuY

Answer (score 9):

Windows 10 IoT is intended to be an "embedded" operating system. So not an OS on its own (like Raspbian is), but more a set of functions and procedures that allow you, the developer, to turn the Raspberry Pi into a custom device, using "familiar" Windows10 programming principles, augmented with access to all the GPIO peripherals connected to the rPi. Let's say you want to build an automated ticket dispenser for an event - you connect printing hardware, a screen and a few buttons to the rPi, write a GUI for the user interface, package the whole thing in a nice looking box and connect it to network and power.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 10 IoT basically is a skeleton of Windows 10 for you to test apps on. Once it came out, there was no GUI, and unless you're making an app for Windows 10, there's not much point for installing it. I learned that the hard way...

Comment: Your shaking up the wrong skeleton. IoT, is NOT Windows 10. The error is easy to make since they labelled it Windows 10 IoT, just because it uses the new .NET Core 5, which is a simplified version of .NET 5 - Its nice to have LXDE with Debian on Pi... but that took years to make. Maybe somebody will make a similar GUI like thing for IoT, only time will tell. IoT is very useful for C# flavoured users and universal apps, full GUI access - you can do Python too and C++ , but just like Rasbpian had issues in the very beginning so does WinIOT

Comment: Exactly. You should comment on his post not mine.