# Raspberry Pi Touch LCD Screen problem when GPIO connected

Tags: gpio, pi-2, touchscreen, windows-iot

I am using a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B. I have a 3.5 inch Touch Display LCD for Raspberry Pi.

When I start the Raspberry Pi with the attached touch screen it shows only a white screen on the Display.

The Screen is connected via the GPIO port.  I am using the Windows IOT OS.

**1) Can a screen be connected to the Raspberry Pi like this?

2) Why is only a White (Blank) Screen showing?**

Comment: Can you post a picture of you got it connected. I dont understand how its connected to GPIO? You mean HDMI, and then the Serial for touch to GPIO, correct? That "serial" may be USB and it possibly requires a USB driver or a Serial mouse driver (which would be very strange)?

Comment: What 'Touch Display" are you trying to connect? What methods/protocol  (SPI, I2C, UART Serial etc.) the display use?  There is no 'GPIO' port as such; the 40 pin connector have a few different functions; and the GPIO ports are exposed there.

Comment: I have  used 3.5 Inch Touch screen [Waveshare Spotpear] (http://www.waveshare.com/3.5inch-rpi-lcd-a.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I don't imagine windows 10 IOT OS will detect the screen as plug and play.  You may need to write software to interface with the screen yourself.

Comment: Relevant: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/36828/5538

Answer (score 0):

[W10 IOT](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/iot) when running on RPI is a headless system due limitations imposed by the amount of RAM memory available.

You should handle your W10 using **powershell**; after the proper installation of [WinRM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781778(v=ws.10).aspx), run [Enter-PsSession](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849707.aspx) '-ComputerName ` only then you can execute remote commands on your Raspberry IOT device.

Your probably noticed that the HDMI is basically, not in use and there is no [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface). However, there are drivers to use the GPIO ports and you can make it great [IOT](https://www.hackster.io/windows-iot/internet-connected-led-445551) device.

Comment: What limitations are there on the RAM when headless? When I connected my HDMI I get the default app showing, similar to the web interface. Could you expand a bit please.

Comment: RAM and Headless are disjoint issues. How much memory will depend on the o/s your are using. To run the HDMI, the GPO requires physical memory, the amount depends on screen resolution, color depth and FPS; the amount can be substantial. Windows IOT was designed to run 'headless', however, he can make use of the HDMI port. The reason run headless is to minimize the code footprint eliminating the GUI. So, to answer your question: I don't know.

Comment: Win IoT stack loads the "GPU" driver whether you plug HDMI in or not. I though we were talking about Win10 IoT. I will test this, but I am pretty sure if you boot with no HDMI the RAM will be used the same as no HDMI. I suppose the GPU RAM may make a difference, but even 16MB is good enough for the Universal Apps to run without OpenGL rendering.(I mean using actual 3D rendering, the GUI is OpenGL but the basic 2D implementation)- I am sorry, I may have misunderstood your answer due to language barrier though.

Comment: But How can I Driver Install and Download ?

Help me and show any complete example Link.

Comment: Win10-IOT works with headed and headless apps - only one headed app can be active at a time.
I have apps that use a display connected to HDMI - example https://www.adafruit.com/products/2407 or simply a computer monitor / tv