# How can I run my windows application on Raspberry Pi2.?

Tags: pi-2, operating-systems, c#

I am new to Raspberry Pi 2, I have a windows application and a windows service which I wanted to run on Raspberry Pi2. I have windows 10 IOT installed on Raspberry Pi 2.

I had refereed to some sites that we need to install mono. If I am not wrong mono totally different again I need to write the whole code for mono, can any explain how can I run windows application and service which are compiled in x86 mode.

Any suggestions how we could install Winodws 7 or Windows 8 would also helpful.

Comment: You can't install WIN 7 or 8 on the Pi.

Comment: Q.v. http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/36828/5538

Answer (score 2):

Mono is only needed if you want run C# under Raspbian or
another Linux.

Note that Windows 10 "IoT Core" for the Raspberry Pi does
not support WinForms. You need to program for the UWP.

Recompilation should be unnecessary if your code is
**pure C# with no native code** since C#  (*not* VB6/ C++ / Delphi) normally runs on VMs (CLRs). Both Mono and Windows "IoT Core" might not support all features available on Windows Desktop CLRs though , you will have to check that manually.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to run x86 CPU code in ARM CPUs.

Yes, you have to rewrite your program in C# which can be ran with mono.

C# programs can also be ran with Linux as long as you develop the application with mono.

(Almost) all windows versions except Windows 10 IOT are for x86 processors. Windows 10 IOI is for ARM processors which the raspberry pi has. The processors are completely different.

Good luck rewriting your app!

Also, there's no real OS in Windows 10 IOT. It's all commands and it's strip bare of any programs you're familiar with Windows.

Comment: Wrong: Windows 10 also targets smartphones and therefore supports the ARM just fine. Your app obviously will need to be recompiled for ARM as well. And sure, MineSweeper is missing from Windows 10 IOT, but your app probably isn't going to break on that.

Comment: There are many versions of Windows that can run on architectures other than x86.  Windows CE and Windows Mobile are two huge examples, even if they are no longer current OS's.